# Convert minutes to Hours - Minutes including Days

Tags: c#

I want to convert minutes to Hours-Minutes, so I have

```
var minutesToTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(totalTime);
```

There my `totalTime` equals to `20710` and when variable minutesToTime is evaluated value is: `14.09:10:00` so I do:

```
var formattedTime = string.Format("{0:00} Hours {1:00} Minutes", minutesToTime.Hours, minutesToTime.Minutes);
```

the problem is I only get Hours and minutes, so my result is `09 Hours 10 Minutes` instead 345 minutes I should get.  How can I that 14 days in minutes too?

Comment: What exact output do you want here, it's not clear to me?

Comment: Yeah this is completely confusing, however im 99.34% sure he wants the output as  `345 Hours and 10 Minutes`

Comment: Probably yes, so should be using `minutesToTime.TotalHours`

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "345 _hours_" rather than minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Days` property:

```
var formattedTime = string.Format(
                    "{0:00} Hours {1:00} Minutes",
                    (minutesToTime.Days * 24) + minutesToTime.Hours, 
                    minutesToTime.Minutes);
```

### EDIT:

After Camilo's suggestion, I think you can use `TotalHours` like this to avoid a lengthy calculation as well:

```
var formattedTime = string.Format("{0:00} Hours {1:00} Minutes", (int)minutesToTime.TotalHours, minutesToTime.Minutes);
```

Comment: Or the [TotalHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx) property and avoid the manual calculation...?

Comment: The problem with that is `TotalHours` gives minutes as a fraction, but apparently the user wants the minutes as a whole number. So you're going to have to do a calculation anyway?

Comment: I'd rather use `Math.Floor(...)` than a cast.